# Is it possible to connect two PCs using ethernet cable and play diablo in multiplayer mode?

Tags: diablo

I want to use my laptop and desktop for playing diablo-1 in multiplayer mode? how do i configure and connect them? I use win-7 os.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general network setup.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to connect two computers using a cable and create a local network on which to play multiplayer games (including Diablo). That's more of a networking how-to question than a gaming one, though. Depending on the card in your laptop/pc you may need a crossover cable rather than a standard ethernet cable.

Comment: do you even google? I bet there are enough answers on "how to connect 2 pcs for local gaming". Or you can just play it via *Battle.Net*

Answer (score 3):

If you use a [crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable), you can directly connect two computers without having to use an ethernet switch. This would allow you to play Diablo (and any other multiplayer games) between the two computers.